# Shifting and Re-organizing Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array, let's say: LRU_frame[] = {4,1,0,3}

I have a random() function that spits out a random number. If the random number n is contained in the array LRU_frame, then, n should be on LRU_frame[0] and everything else must be shifted down accordingly.

For example if random() gives me a 0, the new LRU_frame[] = {0,4,1,3}

Another example, if random() gives me a 3, the new LRU_frame[] = {3,4,1,0}

How do I do this for any Array size with any number of elements in it?

I know how to shift arrays by adding a new element on LRU_frame[0] but have no idea on how to re-organize the array like I need.

This is the code I have so far and let's assume char a is the random number(casted into char) to use and re-organize the array.

```
public static void LRU_shiftPageRef(char a) {
    for (int i = (LRU_frame.length - 2); i >= 0; i--) {

        LRU_frame[i + 1] = LRU_frame[i];
    }
    LRU_frame[0] = a;

}
```

Comment: Why do you cast the random number to a char?  Or do you mean that you have an array of chars?

Comment: Is there a reason why you must use an array rather than an ArrayList which already has the ability to dynamically grow and insert elements at any location moving existing entries to the right?

Comment: Yup, its an array of chars. I said that to clear up any confusion with numbers and characters.

Comment: @jcmwright80: Good point! but the project has much more things to do and I have written everything using arrays. It would take a lot of time for me to go back and change everything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good idea, you only need to find the position of the `a` element in the array and start the cycle from it, instead of `LRU_frame.length`.

```
int index = -1;

// find the positon of 'a' in the array
for (int i = 0; i <= (LRU_frame.length - 1); i++) {
    if (LRU_frame[i] == a) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

// if it is present, do roughly the same thing as before
if (index > -1) {
    for (int i = (index - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        LRU_frame[i + 1] = LRU_frame[i];
    }
    LRU_frame[0] = a;
}
```

However if you can use `ArrayLists` it gets much easier.

```
// declaration
ArrayList<Integer> LRU_frame = new ArrayList<Integer>();

...

if (LRU_frame.contains(a)) {
    LRU_frame.remove((Integer) a);
    LRU_frame.add(0, a);
}
```

Comment: While your code works fine most of the time, LRU_frame remains unchanged when a=0. I ran multiple tests and it does not work for 0.

Comment: @summerNight fixed, first condition should be `<=` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be the sort of thing you are after:

```
public static void LRU_shiftPageRef(char a) {
    int index = indexOf(a);
    if (index == -1) {
        //not currently in array so create a new array 1 bigger than existing with a in newArray[0] or ignore depending on functionality required.
    } else if (index > 0) {
        //Set first entry as a and shift existing entries right
        char insertChar = a;
        char nextChar = LRU_frame[0];
        for (int i =0; i < index; i++) {
             LRU_frame[i] = insertChar;
             insertChar = nextChar;
             nextChar = LRU_frame[i+1];
        }
        LRU_frame[index] = insertChar;
    } else {
        //do nothing a is already at first position
    }
}

public static int indexOf(char a) {
    for (int i=0; i < LRU_frame.length; i++) {
        if (LRU_frame[i] == a) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.sort(LRU_frame);` to sort the entire array, or `Arrays.sort(LRU_frame, fromIndex, toIndex));` to sort part of the array.

`Arrays` class has other useful methods like `copyOfRange`.